# Contact Score Rollup on Account Object

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, after-trigger

I have to calculate the sum of related child object(contact) on field (Score1__c and Score2__c) to parent object Account object field(AccountScore1__c and AccountScore2__c)

my code is working on insert update undelete but not working with ****delete**** event

```
trigger ContactScoreRollup on Contact (after insert,after update,after undelete,Before Delete) {
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> accountsToUpdate1 = new List<Account>();
    if(trigger.isinsert || trigger.isundelete || trigger.isupdate){
        for(Contact con :Trigger.new){
            accountIds.add(con.AccountId);
        }
    }
    if(Trigger.isdelete || Trigger.isupdate){
        for(contact con : Trigger.old){
            accountids.add(con.Accountid);
        }
        accountIds.remove(null);
    }

    for(AggregateResult ar :[SELECT AccountId,SUM(Score1__c) sumammount1 FROM Contact  where AccountId in: accountIds  GROUP BY AccountId]){

        accountsToUpdate.add(new Account(Id = (Id)ar.get('AccountId'),AccountScore1__c= (Decimal)ar.get('sumammount1') ));
    }

    for(AggregateResult arr :[SELECT AccountId,SUM(Score2__c) sumammount2 FROM Contact  where AccountId in: accountIds  GROUP BY AccountId]){

        accountsToUpdate1.add(new Account(Id = (Id)arr.get('AccountId'),Account_Score2__c= (Decimal)arr.get('sumammount2') ));
    }
    update accountsToUpdate;
    update accountsToUpdate1;
}
```

Comment: It is completely unnecessary to maintain two separate lists and queries. Also you should move `remove(null)` outside that second `if` condition. Neither of these changes will affect `delete` functionality, but should be made in addition to moving this logic *out of your trigger body* and into a service layer. Or better yet, into a generic rollup utility. Better still, use a rollup utility which has already been written and well tested such as [dlrs](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries).

Answer (score 1):

You need to query *after* delete, or you won't get accurate query results. Also, you need to set the default values back to zero, because if the account does not have any remaining contacts, this won't be reflected in the update. Finally, you should combine the account updates to a single update. Since you're grouping by the same result each time, you can also combine the queries. Here's a revised version of your code:

```
trigger ContactScoreRollup on Contact (after insert,after update,after undelete,after Delete) {
    Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>();

    if(Trigger.new != null) {
        for(Contact con :Trigger.new){
            accounts.put(con.AccountId, new Account(Id=con.AccountId, AccountScore1__c=0.0));
        }
    }
    if(Trigger.old != null) {
        for(contact con : Trigger.old){
            accounts.put(con.AccountId, new Account(Id=con.AccountId, Account_Score2__c=0.0));
        }
    }
    accountIds.remove(null);

    for(AggregateResult ar :[SELECT AccountId AccountId,SUM(Score1__c) sumamount1, SUM(Score2__c) sumammount2 FROM Contact  where AccountId in: accountIds  GROUP BY AccountId]) {
        Account acct = accounts.get((Id)ar.get('AccountId'));
        acct.AccountScore1__c = (Decimal)ar.get('sumammount1');
        acct.Account_Score2__c = (Decimal)ar.get('sumammount2');
    }
    update accounts.values();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

run a for loop on trigger.old above the aggregate function and remove one aggregate function.and add after delete trigger context variable
add a loop like this

```
for(Contact con :trigger.old){AccountId.add(con.AccountId);
```

}